# How should I locate my scripts in my web page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing an ASP MVC web application using some web technologies like Javascript and JQuery.

Due to the big use of script in my project, I am facing a lot of problems with the right position and order of these script inside my code.

Indeed, I am getting always errors in my browser.

For example, when I locate these Scripts in my Head tag by this order :

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/template/web/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

I will get these errors that mention a problem with the definition of the JQuery :

> jquery.validate.min.js:16 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not
>   defined
>       at jquery.validate.min.js:16 jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js:19 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
>       at jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js:19 Index:1436 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
>       at HTMLDocument. (http://localhost:60585/(S(yjivkav5ujyyjrcrznjabbqp))/Home/Index:1436:26)
>       at i (http://localhost:60585/template/web/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2:27151)
>       at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (http://localhost:60585/template/web/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2:27914)
>       at Function.ready (http://localhost:60585/template/web/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2:29707)
>       at HTMLDocument.J (http://localhost:60585/template/web/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2:29892)

But when I try to locate all these scripts in the bottom of the page like this :

```
<script src="/template/web/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

These errors will appear :

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).ziehharmonika is not a function
>       at HTMLDocument. (http://localhost:60585/(S(ls4ko4ghxnphalf2azyphinz))/Home/Index:1462:23)
>       at i (http://localhost:60585/template/web/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2:27151)
>       at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (http://localhost:60585/template/web/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2:27914)
>       at Function.ready (http://localhost:60585/template/web/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2:29707)
>       at HTMLDocument.J (http://localhost:60585/template/web/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2:29892)
>   Index:1441 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).JiSlider is not a function
>       at http://localhost:60585/(S(ls4ko4ghxnphalf2azyphinz))/Home/Index:1441:20
>       at dispatch (http://localhost:60585/template/web/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js:3:7537)
>       at r.handle (http://localhost:60585/template/web/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js:3:5620)

Comment: It’s not the position of the block, it’s the order. You’re loading jQuery *after* the scripts that need it. Fix the order.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen thx for your reply. Yes I was wondering too about the right order. I didn't which one come first and which last

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put this one (which loads jQuery) first in your list of scripts:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks man, it is work. I thought I tried this combination but it seems that it was missing sth, thats why it didn't worked to me

Answer (score 0):

You need to put jQuery files in the correct order.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```